# Parsing sub sentences from a full sentence with NLTK parser

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

I am looking for the NLTK parser which can parse sub sentences from a full sentence.

For example:

> I am walking in the park

and according to some grammar, the results from the parser are going to be like

> Sentence 1: I am {0:2}
>
> Sentence 2: I am walking {0:3}
>
> Sentence 3: I am walking in {0:4}
>
> Sentence 4: I am walking in the park {0:6}

Is there any module which can do something like this?

Comment: Why are "I am." and "I am walking in." not sentences ?

Comment: and what have you tried till now ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak Yes and thanks, it can also be the sentences.
So far I found the A* parser on (2.9)
http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08-extras.html
which seems to be a candidate for my issue, I'm trying this parser now but not sure will it work.